# XML canonicalization in JAVA 1.5

Tags: java, xml, canonicalization

Does anyone know of any method to canonicalize XML document in java 1.5, without using Canonicalizer class at Apache XML Security project? I can't upgrade java to a newer version and i can't use any external libraries.

By saying i can't use any external libraries i meant that i can use only JRE1.5 system library, can't import any additional .JAR files.

Comment: Define "*external*" library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [DomConfiguration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration.html) class, set the "canonical-form" configuration parameter to true, then call [normalizeDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#normalizeDocument--):

```
void canonicalize(Document doc) {
    doc.getDomConfig().setParameter("canonical-form", true);
    doc.normalizeDocument();
}
```

The above methods are present in Java 1.5: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html